# How to use Pact Matcher for values other than 'Strings'

Tags: pact

In pact-jvm (groovy on consumer side and gradle on the provider side), I'm trying to use Pact matchers like below:

```
name regexp(~/\w+/,'sony')
```

Will Pact matcher regex work only for Strings ? For values other than strings, do I need to use Pact term ?

If the answer is 'yes' for the above two questions. Please explain me how to use Pact term in groovy style.

I have tried using Pact term like below:

```
date Pact.Term(generate :"02/11/2013", matcher:/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)
```

But getting groovy - MethodMissingException.
My complete response body for reference:

```
withBody {
                id regexp('[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}','e8cda07e-849f-49c2-94d6-aaa5c4ab7fcd')
                name regexp(~/\w+/,'sony')
                date Pact.Term(generate :"02/11/2013", matcher:/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex only applies to strings.

If you want to match a date, I'd suggest using the `date` matcher, e.g.

```
withBody {
                id regexp('[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}','e8cda07e-849f-49c2-94d6-aaa5c4ab7fcd')
                name regexp(~/\w+/,'sony')
                date date("dd/MM/yyyy", "02/11/2013")
         }
```

See the available DSL methods https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-groovy#dsl-methods-1